# Passing variable as Hash element in Ruby not working

Tags: ruby, hash

I have following code in a test.rb file:

```
hello = { :credit => "Testing" }
acc = ":credit"
puts hello[a.to_sym]
```

When I run it as: `ruby test.rb`, I am supposed to get the value of the Hash element (Testing) but I am getting nothing.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colon in the string is what is screwing you up.

```
1.9.3p429 :003 > acc.to_sym
:":credit"
```

You need to make it just "credit"

```
1.9.3p429 :004 > acc = "credit"
"credit"
1.9.3p429 :005 > acc.to_sym
:credit
1.9.3p429 :006 > hello[acc.to_sym]
"Testing"
```

Comment: Wow! thanks for the quick answer Eugene. It worked! Shame on me, I did a silly mistake. :)